# Create Appointment in my secondary outlook calendar (Ews managed API)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, outlook, exchangewebservices

I have a primary outlook calender and a secondary outlook calendar with the name "Test".

I am able to create an appointment in my primary calendar. How do I create agreement instead of my secondary calendar named test?

```
    ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();

   service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("xxxx", "paswordxx");

    service.AutodiscoverUrl("xxxx", RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);


    Appointment appointment = new Appointment(service);

    appointment.Subject = "Exchange Webservice - Opret en appointment";
    appointment.Body = "En appointment oprettes og sættes til 'Busy'";
    appointment.Start = new DateTime(2017, 3, 29, 9, 15, 0);
    appointment.LegacyFreeBusyStatus = LegacyFreeBusyStatus.OOF;
    appointment.End = appointment.Start.AddHours(2);
    appointment.Save(SendInvitationsMode.SendToNone);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this , first get test folder id like below and then save with folder id.

_globalService parameter is ExchangeService object , can pass as parameter to GetFolder() or use as global variable.

```
 private FolderId GetFolder()
    {
      FolderId  _gloableFolderId = null;
        try
        {
            //Find folders
            FolderView view = new FolderView(20);
            view.PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly);
            view.PropertySet.Add(FolderSchema.DisplayName);
            view.Traversal = FolderTraversal.Deep;
            FindFoldersResults findFoldersResults = _globalService.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, view);
            foreach (var folder in findFoldersResults)
            {
                if (folder is Folder)
                {
                    if (folder.DisplayName.ToUpper() == "TEST") 
                    {
                        _gloableFolderId = folder.Id;
                        return _gloableFolderId;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          // Log exception or return main calender
        }

        return _gloableFolderId;
    }
```

save like this

```
 FolderId _folderID = GetFolder();
appointment.Save(_folderID,SendInvitationsMode.SendToNone);
```